# Selection area: bound by div and change it's color for all elements

Tags: html, css, textselection

I am new to HTML/CSS and I faced with two troubles with elements selection.

I write a html page, which contains a centered div and elements inside it.

I have two troubles:

1. How to bound selection area by div borders?
2. Some elements use "old" selection color, how to change it?

---

I placed two images below for better understanding what I mean:

without selection:
[image: without selection]

with selection:
[image: with selection]

---

I tried to change selection background color by following peace of css code:

```
*::selection {
color: #330066;
background:yellow;
}

*::-moz-selection {
color: #330066;
background:yellow;
}
```

---

[EDIT]:
You can see a similar code here: http://jsfiddle.net/phvoronov/7ZQ5z/1/.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle? It is also not clear what goes wrong? How bound selection area by div borders? It is only on text not the padding or borders. http://jsfiddle.net/g943Z/3/. The universal * selector will aplly this on all elements in the document.

Comment: @JohanVandenRym, i added a link to jsfiddle (see EDIT to my post).

Comment: @JohanVandenRym, "How bound selection area by div borders?" When I select elements inside my main div, selection area must be only inside my div, not through the entire width of the page.

Comment: You specify on what div you want to apply it div::selection {}

Comment: @JohanVandenRym
I want it on my main div (id="main-div").
If you mean that i should add #main-div::selection{}, it doesn't help (see http://jsfiddle.net/phvoronov/7ZQ5z/2/) or I did it wrong.